# vertical scrollbar missing

Tags: html, scrollbar

If you view this HTML css site in either 1024x768 resolution or on a mobile device, the content that extends vertically beyond the browser is hidden and there is no vert scrollbar to do so. Is there any way to force it?

[www.marketbridge.net](http://www.marketbridge.net)

thx

Comment: I see scrollbars when I try using a 1004x718 window.

Comment: i'm using safari and there are none. i did try it with IE and they do exist but don't scroll all the way down so they are not of much use.

Answer (score 0):

On Apple OS, scroll bars are never shown anymore. I often find this a nuisance also, but I guess MacOS/iOS users are used to this. You could make some flyover indication with JavaScript using scroll height and scrollposition, but I guess you're better consistently using a pagefooter. This way the user 'feels' there is still content.
Another way to achieve this is only the upper half of the last displayed line of text is displayed (through JavaScript). The same effect is reached by displaying a rectangle with increasing opacity (0 to 100%) over the bottom of the viewport that makes the bottom of the viewport seem to fade out. If you make sure the page's bottom padding is equal or greater than the gradient, you have a nice indication of continuation, and the good thing is you can do with pure HTML and css.